# Perfectly center images in react column

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm having difficulty aligning some images inside of bootstrap 4 columns. I have tried using the CSS property text-align: center, and this will center the image horizontal. My columns take up a large amount of the view port though, so I also need the images to be centered vertical.

Here is what my react component is returning. class="img13" is what i am attempting to center.

```
<div id="border">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row tower">
                <div class="col-sm-3 towers" id="tower1">
                    <div class="tower-icon"><img class="img13" src={character}></img></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS that I currently have. It hard codes an image to be centered in one column, but if i change the display size for the site, or use a different image, it is no longer centered.
.row{
display: flex;}

```
.towers {
    color: white;
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative;
}
.tower-icon{
    margin-top: 52%;
    margin-bottom: 48%;
    
}
.img13{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Start Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAXQ7.png) here is an attached picture of what the component looks like. The background is the column, and the 'start' picture is the class="img13"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the div containing the image to be the height of the viewport, then set its display property to flex. Then give the image a `margin: auto`.

```
.tower-icon {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}
 .img13 {
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! This works perfectly. I changed the .tower-icon height to just be 100% so that way it is centered with the column instead of the view port.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of flexbox and auto center align everything within the `.tower-icon` div like so:

```
.tower-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Just please note that the logo will horizontally and vertically center within the constraints of the column with the `.col-sm-3` class.

Test link:

https://jsbin.com/sekosibizo/edit?css,output